# Start Downloading on download page

Tags: php

I want some help, I want download some files from website, the problem is that, when we are click to download button on detail.php page, the download start on detail.php page. This is my link on download button Link.

```
http://localhost/website/download.php?filename=fun.jpg
```

But I want when click on this link then open `http://localhost/website/download.php?filename=fun.jpg` `download.php page` and after some seconds downloading start automatically..

Comment: Please give me the URL of your project as soon as it's online so I can download all of you PHP source files? :) Sorry for being so cynical, but in all seriousness: *Please* make sure you sanitize your `filename` parameter well so people can only download what you want them to?

Comment: This project on my local system, but for help I create dummy download link on my dummy server please visit this link and provide me the Solution `http://webtaq.com/download/`

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 urls: one for the background page for your download, and one for the real download. On the background page, use a javascript redirection to redirect to your real download page.